# Vim Solarized Light theme with wrong colors

Tags: vim, terminal, macvim

I'm having a hard time getting my Solarized Light theme to work properly on Vim.

For some reason the color palette gets messed up and it doesn't look as expected. The contrast is different. But when I run Vim through MacVim, the colours look perfect as opposed to when I run Vim via Terminal.app (w/ bash).

[image: Terminal.app vs MacVim]

This is what my `~/.vimrc` looks like:

```
let g:solarized_termcolors=256                                                            
let g:solarized_termtrans=1                                                               

colorscheme solarized
```

On my Terminal.app under "Advanced" options I've set "Declare terminal as" to `xterm-256color` but that doesn't seem to fix the issue.
I've also tried to mess around with the `t_Co` value (setting it to `8`, `16` and `256`) and it didn't fixed the issue either.

This seem to be a common issue for Terminal.app users and even though there are a variety of threads created on the subject, I've not found an actual solution to the problem.

Comment: I'm going to assume that someone didnt properly assign the termbg value correctly. Since the gui version is working can you run `:hi` to show all of the highlights defined at that moment? If you are already using colorizer this should be a breeze to identify that bad highlight..

Comment: Take a look at this, maybe your problem is also with the terminal enforcing a certain minimum contrast for each cell: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29487/is-it-possible-to-disable-terminals-automatic-tweaking-of-colors-in-lion

Answer (score 1):

Do you have solarized theme also installed for Terminal.app?
If yes, then you don't need `let g:solarized_termcolors=256`. This is only required if you have ANSI colours different from solarized palette, as stated on the [official website](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized/vim-colors-solarized):

> If you use Solarized without these colors, Solarized will need to be told to degrade its colorscheme to a set compatible with the limited 256 terminal palette (whereas by using the terminal’s 16 ansi color values, you can set the correct, specific values for the Solarized palette).
>
> If you do use the custom terminal colors, solarized.vim should work out of the box for you. If you are using a terminal emulator that supports 256 colors and don’t want to use the custom Solarized terminal colors, you will need to use the degraded 256 colorscheme. To do so, simply add the following line before the colorschem solarized line:
>
> `let g:solarized_termcolors=256`

So if it is the case just delete this line. I had the same problem at first and without this line everything worked perfectly good.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in how the default Terminal.app handle colors. I've switched to [iTerm2](http://iterm2.com) and now everything looks exactly as expected.

Thanks for the help.